# Get all the frontend blocks template(layout) in admin backend side?

Tags: magento-1.7

I will describe the situation in more detail. I create simple extension. In my config.xml i add events.

```
<events>
     <core_block_abstract_to_html_before>
       <observers>
         <my_info_core_block_abstract_to_html_before>
           <type>singleton</type>
           <class>my_info_Model_Observer</class>
         <method>insertBlock</method>
         </my_info_core_block_abstract_to_html_before>
       </observers>
     </core_block_abstract_to_html_before>
</events>
```

Then i create my model for observer when my function insertBlock

```
public function insertBlock($observer) {

/* get data from db */
$my_search_block = Mage::getModel('my/my')->load(1)->getData('data');


$_block = $observer->getBlock();
$_type = $_block->getType();

/* if the block is desired */
if ($_type == $my_search_block) {

$_child = clone $_block;
    $_child->setType('test/block');
    $_block->setChild('child', $_child);
    $_block->setTemplate('my/my.phtml');
}

}
```

In my back end of extension I want to get all the blocks and give choice of administrator. Then selected block i put into db and in my observe i compare blocks and display my block

I'm trying to get all the blocks but do not know what function it displays the list of blocks.

```
$layout = Mage::app()->getLayout();
    Zend_Debug::dump($layout);
```

How get all frontend block template(layout) and child-block in the admin backend?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish but a list of all blocks means you want a list of every block ever created in every layout XML on the frontend? That means you'll end up with hundreds of blocks