# How to get frontend area layout in admin side?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-enterprise

I asked the question but did not get an answer to [it](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/10362/3791). 
Now i understand how get all block in pages, but i get only current page blocks. For example:

```
  $layout = Mage::app()->loadArea(Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::AREA_FRONTEND)->getLayout();
  /* then i get all blocks from that page*/
```

How to get frontend area, when i in backend?? I know that it should be simple, but when i want get AREA_FRONTEND, i get my current page, but i need get frontend area.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Old question, but here goes.

Have not tried this myself, but may help in the right direction.
`$selectedStoreId` will be the id of the sore who's theme you want to get to.
This is how preview in magento EE does it.

```
Mage::app()->getLocale()->emulate($selectedStoreId);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::app()->getStore($selectedStoreId));

Mage::getDesign()->setArea('frontend')
        ->setStore($selectedStoreId);

$designChange = Mage::getSingleton('core/design')
        ->loadChange($selectedStoreId);

if ($designChange->getData()) {
    Mage::getDesign()->setPackageName($designChange->getPackage())
            ->setTheme($designChange->getTheme());
}
```

and use `Mage::app()->getLocale()->revert();` to go back to admin theme.