# Creating block in cronjob looks for template in admin instead of frontend html

Tags: layout, cron, blocks

In a custom modul that creates cronjobs I create a block like this

```
Mage::app('default')->loadArea('frontend');
    $layout = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout');
    $layout->getUpdate()->load('default');

    $block = $layout->createBlock('catalog/product_view_type_configurable');
```

and run `$block->getJsonConfig();`

In there, another block is created

```
$this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_view_attributes');
```

and its template set

```
$childBlock->setTemplate('catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml')
```

But I get the error:

```
Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml
```

the file is in my frontend/template1/template2/catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml

How can I fix this? Obviously, I just don't want to copy the file to that directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this does the trick

```
Mage::app()->getLocale()->emulate($store);
        Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::app()->getStore($store));

        Mage::getDesign()->setArea('frontend')
            ->setStore($store)
            ->setPackageName('template') //Name of Package
            ->setTheme('template');

        Mage::getSingleton('core/design')
            ->loadChange(1);

        $layout = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout');

        $block = $layout->createBlock('catalog/product_view_type_configurable');
```

credit goes here:
[How to get frontend area layout in admin side?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10381/how-to-get-frontend-area-layout-in-admin-side?rq=1)